# Selector driver.page_source does not return all html

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am writing a code in python with a selector from scrapy.

```
selector = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
```

Is not returning the page's html.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://google.com")

selector = driver.page_source

print(selector)
```